# How can we change base camera perspective after executing setPadding method?

Tags: heremaps-android-sdk

I have moved the center of the map using [setPadding](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.18/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/Map.html#setPadding-int-int-int-int-) method because of the UI on the left side of my view. After that current position marker is in the right place, but the end of the road is still centred to the middle of the screen. How can I change the base camera perspective (principal point) to match the expected state? I am using navigation manager with MapUpdateMode - ROADVIEW.

Current state:
[image: Current state]

Expected state:
[image: Expected state]

I am using HERE SDK for Android (Premium Edition) 3.18.3